# Soap body always blank

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to integrate web services using soap.

This is the xml file:

http://uatapiout.islandhopper.in/Service1.svc?wsdl

And this is code which I am trying:

```
<?php

$wsdl = 'http://uatapiout.islandhopper.in/Service1.svc?wsdl';

$xml_array["RequestType"] = "AvailabilityRQ";
$xml_array["Login"] = array("UserName"=>"test","Password"=>"test","Version"=>"3.0");

$xml_array["CheckAvailabilityCriteria"] = array("CheckIn" => "07/05/2017","CheckOut"=> "07/11/2017","CountryID"=> "MAU","CityID" => "MAU","Currency" => "USD","Adult" => "2","Rooms"=>array("Room"=>array("Adult"=>"2","Child"=>"0")));

$trace = true;
$exceptions = true;

try
{

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); 

    $response = $client->HotelSearch($xml_array );

    print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
    print_r($client->__getLastResponse());

}

catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error!";
    echo $e ->getMessage ();
    echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}
```

And $client->__getLastRequest() always gives me blank body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:HotelSearch/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So, the  question is that why this request has a blank body.

Please suggest me, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is sample xml request:

```
<XMLRequest>
<RequestType>AvailabilityRQ</RequestType>
<Login>
    <UserName>UserName</UserName>
    <Password>Password</Password>
    <Version>3.0</Version>
</Login>
<CheckAvailabilityCriteria>
    <CheckIn>07/05/2016</CheckIn>
    <CheckOut>07/11/2016</CheckOut>
    <CountryID>MAU</CountryID>
    <CityID>MAU</CityID>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <HotelCode></HotelCode>
    <HotelName></HotelName>
    <ClientNationality></ClientNationality>
    <Rooms>
        <Room>
           <Adult>2</Adult>
           <Child>2</Child>
           <ChildAges>
                <ChildAge>7</ChildAge>
                <ChildAge>14</ChildAge>
           </ChildAges>
        </Room>
        <Room>
           <Adult>2</Adult>
           <Child>0</Child>
       </Room>
    </Rooms>
</CheckAvailabilityCriteria>
</XMLRequest>
```

Comment: what is that `$response = $client->HotelSearch($xml_array );` ?

Comment: That would be the method that he needs to call. But the problem is with $xml_array. You're not making a proper Soap Header.

Comment: @hassan, thanks for reply. yes, it it a method in API

Comment: @Elbarto, thanks for reply. I am newbie for soap and not able to get good tutorial and link to do that. Please suggest a link.

Comment: What is the exact xml soapheader that your api is waiting for authentifictation ?

Comment: @Elbarto, As I attached link for WDSL file. It does not have any header I guess. What type of header you are asking for?

Comment: Can you link any documentation of the api you want to use ? Do you need to authenticate yourself in order to use the web services ? The soapClient in the php manual has some examples (especially in the comments section) http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support.

Now, I am doing that using nusaop lib.

This is the code:

```
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$wsdl = 'wdls url';

$xml_array["RequestType"] = "AvailabilityRQ";
$xml_array["Login"] = array("UserName"=>"username","Password"=>"password","Version"=>"version");

$xml_array["CheckAvailabilityCriteria"] = array("CheckIn" => "07/05/2017","CheckOut"=> "07/11/2017","CountryID"=> "MAU","CityID" => "MAU","Currency" => "USD","Rooms"=>array("Room"=>array("Adult"=>"2","Child"=>"0")));

$xml_array1['XMLRequest'] =$xml_array;


$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, false);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$err = $client->getError();

if ($err)
{
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    exit();
}

$result = $client->call('HotelSearch', $xml_array1,'','http://tempuri.org/IService1/HotelSearch',false,false,'','');

if ($client->fault) 
{

    echo '<h2>Fault (Expect - The request contains an invalid SOAP body)</h2>';
}
else 
{
    $err = $client->getError();

    if ($err) 
    {
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    }
    else
    {

        $result_count = $array_result['TotalResult'];

        if($result_count)
        {
            $hotels_list = $array_result['AvailHotels']['Hotel'];

            for($i=0; $i<count($hotels_list);$i++)
            {
                $hotel_name = $hotels_list[$i]['@attributes']['Name'];
                $hotel_code = $hotels_list[$i]['@attributes']['Code'];

                echo "Hotel name is <i>$hotel_name</i> and hotel code is <i>$hotel_code</i>";

                echo "</br></br>";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope, this will help someone :)